# Close fancybox and submit form in parent page?

Tags: dialog, fancybox, form-submit

I have some HTML elements like these:

```
<form id="my_form" name="my_form" method="post">
 Some of Form elements
</form>

<a id="open_dialog" href="#dialog">Open Dialog</a>
<div id="dialog">
Content
<a onclick="parent.$.fancybox.close();">Close and Submit Form</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("a#open_dialog").fancybox({
    afterClose : function() {
        $("#my_form").submit();
    }
});
</script>
```

When I click the link "Close and Submit Form", the #dialog closed as expected but the form#my_form don't submit.

How can I submit the form when close a fancybox?

Comment: I see no "action" attribute in your form... may that be the cause ? (I don't think so but you never now...) Did you test if the function set as afterClose event is actually called ?

Comment: Yes. I did test the afterClose event. It was called properly. Maybe I'll try to add the form action and let you know if it works.

Comment: Are all the elements in the same  page? Are the DOM elements ready when you execute `.submit()`? if not sure, wrap the fancybox script inside the `.ready()` method. @Bartdude : the form should submit even without an `action` attribute (it doesn't mean it will be processed though)